# How do I access a character at an index in a stored string?

Tags: c++, string, text

So, lets say I do this:

> getline ( cin , message );

Can I access the nth character in this message?

Comment: This is a character? I could pass this through a predefined function which takes `char my_car` data type, yes?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the index that you want to access.

```
char ch=message[n-1]
```

n-1 is used since the index starts from 0. so, n-1 accesses the nth element

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `char& string::operator[] (size_t pos)` ([http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/)):

```
 char ch = message[nth-1];
```

Comment: I can accept the answer in 11 minutes. Thank you Yang. Are you Hmong?

Comment: @Trancot Thanks. I'm not Hmong.

Comment: @Trancot That's the longest 11 minutes I have ever seen.